# How to chain operator on flatmap

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

in the below code, in the companion object, the create method sould return Single. as the code indicates, the final operator i used is flatmap() to convert the retrofit object to Maybe.just to make sure it is not null.
however, when i usse this operator

```
                 .flatMap {retrofit->Maybe.just(retrofit)}
```

i could not chain any further operators to convert the returned value from the aforementioned flatmap to Single. please let me know why i cant chain any further operators on the aforementioned code, also
please find the code posted below

**code**

```
interface WikiApiService {
@GET("api.php")
fun hitCountCheck(
    @Query("action") action: String,
    @Query("format") format: String,
    @Query("list") list: String,
    @Query("srsearch") srsearch: String
):
        Observable<ResponseObjectModelForQuery.ResultOfQuery>

@GET("api.php")
fun hitContinue2(
    @Query("action") action: String,
    @Query("format") format: String,
    @Query("list") list: String,
    @Query("srsearch") srsearch: String
):
        Observable<ResponseObjectModelForContinueSrOffset.ResultOfContinueSrOffset>

@GET("api.php")
fun hitContinue3(
    @Query("action") action: String,
    @Query("format") format: String,
    @Query("list") list: String,
    @Query("srsearch") srsearch: String
):
        Observable<ResponseObjectModelForContinueContinue.Continue>

//why do we need a companion object
companion object {
    fun create(): Single<WikiApiService>? {
        return Single.just(
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
                .build())
            //workin.flatMap { Maybe.just(it.create(WikiApiService::class.java)).toSingle()}
            .flatMap {retrofit->Maybe.just(retrofit)}
            .//cant chain any further operators

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `flatMapMaybe()` instead:

```
    companion object {
    fun create(): Single<WikiApiService>? {
        return Single.just(
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
                .build())
            //workin.flatMap {  Maybe.just(it.create(WikiApiService::class.java)).toSingle()}
            .flatMapMaybe {retrofit->Maybe.just(retrofit)}
            .//cant chain any further operators

            }
    }
}
```

? or convert the `Maybe` into a `Single` depending on what you wish to chain:

```
    companion object {
    fun create(): Single<WikiApiService>? {
        return Single.just(
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
                .build())
            //workin.flatMap {  Maybe.just(it.create(WikiApiService::class.java)).toSingle()}
            .flatMap {retrofit->Maybe.just(retrofit).toSingle() }
            .//cant chain any further operators

            }
    }
}
```